# Problems with rotation in landscape and portrait view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application I have 2 views, portraitView and landScapeView. And also  my application consists of  many views...

1. When I launch the application both landscape and portrait view is getting displayed side by side.
2. When I launch the application in landscapeview the portraitview is getting displayed..later after rotating and coming back the view is getting proper.

The code I am using is given below...so please suggest me what all changes should be done to overcome above problem as mentioned..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation

{ 

if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {  
    NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE>>");
    portraitView.hidden = YES;
    landscapeView.hidden = NO;

    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-ic_landscape.jpg"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;



}
else if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    NSLog(@"LANDSCAPE<<");
    portraitView.hidden = YES;
    landscapeView.hidden = NO;
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-ic_landscape.jpg"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;

    self.view.hidden = NO;

}
else{
    portraitView.hidden = NO;
    landscapeView.hidden = YES;


    NSLog(@"Portrait");
    UIColor *background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-ic.jpg"]];
    self.view.backgroundColor = background;

    background = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-ic2.jpg"]];
  self.view.backgroundColor = background;

}

return YES;
```

Comment: Why make a different view for landscape and for portrait? Why haven't you fixed the frame size accordingly to the orientation you are in?

Comment: To be more clear you need to use only one view. Set the frame of the view programmatically or through interface builder which is suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your portraitView and landscapeView are both visible on initial launch of the app. The code above is only executed when the orientation *changes* during runtime. If you do insist on using separate views for portrait and landscape then you'll need to detect orientation at launch as well and show / hide the views appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the system calls shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: doesn't mean that it will do so there and then. You want to be using willRotateToInterfaceOrientation and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation, and use autosizing as much as possible. You can also subclass the layout update callback to re-arrange your view. Having two view and showing/hiding them for landscape/portrait is not recommended.